# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, digital-ocean, dokku

using this command "git push dokku master" and deploy ruby on rails using Dokku on Digital Ocean getting me this error

```
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you 
use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add 
the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

I have add mysql2 to the Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

gemfile make sure to scroll down:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
"https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
 gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
 group :development, :test do
   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'devise', '~>4.2'
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~>5.1.0'
gem 'aws-sdk','~> 2.8'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'
gem 'geocomplete_rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.7'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11.1'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.17.1'
gem 'stripe', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'rails-assets-card', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect', '~> 2.10.0'
gem 'chartkick', '~> 2.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'vider'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.8.3'
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

I have database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %> 
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

I ran this command

```
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mysql.git mysql
```

Bundle v is 1.16.3
I ran the following commands

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

The expecting result is to make the following command line work, which that will lead a successful push to server

```
git push dokku master
```

Comment: can you post your Gemfile contents?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I added the gem file make sure to scroll down

Comment: `enter code heregroup` is that a typo? also do you really need `git_source` hackery block?

Comment: sorry that was type is posted here i did edited. I dont think I need git_source. do u think the issue is from this @lacostenycoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating sql to gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.10' fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run with `sudo` prefix?

```
sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mysql.git mysql
```

Do you get any errors?  Also you should set encoding like this:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %> 
  pool: 5
```

You also need to make sure you set the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable

```
dokku config:set DATABASE_URL=<some-db-url-here>
```

#### Update

Reading your error message, perhaps in Gemfile you can try to comment out

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

or try perhaps move it to develop group?  Just a try, not sure.

Comment: I dont think the issue is there but i tried sudo that what i got "fatal: destination path 'mysql' already exists and is not an empty directory."  I added the DATABASE_URL but still getting the same error and changed it to utf8 @lacostenycoder

Answer (score 0):

It seems the database.yml not on the right place.
When you deploy a project, you maybe should put the database.yml manually because this file not in repo.